# CakePHP Fatal Error Call to a member function schema() on a non-object

Tags: php, cakephp, many-to-many, model-associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have some trouble finding a solution for this..

```
Error: Call to a member function schema() on a non-object
File: /Cake/Model/Model.php
Line: 3627
```

In my Database there are the tables **articles**,**hashtags** and the association **articles_hashtags** with the foreignkeys article_id and hashtag_id .. So i am trying to get the information what hashtags each article has..

**My Article Model**

```
class Article extends AppModel {
 public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Hashtag' =>
        array(
            'className' => 'Hashtag',
            'joinTable' => 'articles_hashtags',
            'foreignKey' => 'article_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'hashtag_id',
            'unique' => true,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'with' => ''
               )  
            ); 
          }
```

**Article Controller**

```
class ArticleController extends AppController {
var $name = 'Article';
 public $helpers = array("Html", "Form");
    public function index() 
    {
    $this->set("posts", $this->Article->find("all"));

    } 
}
```

Thanks for your help!!

Additionally: 
If i put the generated sql select query from the debugger sql log into my sql database i get the right results .. so i guess theres something wrong with the controller?!

Comment: check table name seems like it is typo error

Comment: oh no sorry that typo was just here

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same problem so stripped down the `$hasAndBelongsToMany` to minimum keys possible.

The problem is that you are using the 'with' key on the `$hasAndBelongsToMany` array.  Remove this or set it to 'articles_hashtags':

```
class Article extends AppModel {
  public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Hashtag' =>
        array(
            'className' => 'Hashtag',
            'joinTable' => 'articles_hashtags',
            'foreignKey' => 'article_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'hashtag_id',
            'unique' => true,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'with' => 'articles_hashtags'
        )  
      ); 
   }
```

The library model code was attempting to access the value of the 'with' key, which was blank, hence the non-object error.

[From CakePHP docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm), regarding `$hasAndBelongsToMany` array:

> - **with**: Defines the name of the model for the join table. By default CakePHP will auto-create a model for you. Using the example above it would be called IngredientsRecipe. By using this key you can override this default name. The join table model can be used just like any “regular” model to access the join table directly. By creating a model class with such name and filename, you can add any custom behavior to the join table searches, such as adding more information/columns to it.

Comment: So simple, nice work. I was getting the same and as a result of bake constructing the HABTM relationship that includes the blank with setting ('with' => ''). Hours of debugging solved. You rock.

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized object of model *Article* in your controller? You can do this by using field *$uses* in controller. Add following line in *ArticleController*:

```
public $uses = array('Article');
```

Answer (score 0):

[Controllers names are plural](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#controller-conventions)

You dont need declare the model Article in ArticlesController, the cake's magic do it for you.

Comment: Are you still talking about OP?